# Programs & Techniques for finding when a Pointer goes out of scope

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I am a Software intern working on a large project in C++, & I am also a One man team. Daunting (is that how u spell it :P), yes it is, but also fun.

I am running into c++ pointers that end up pointing to NULL (not because the memory is freed/deleted but because, well I dont really know, but I suspect its because the objects I point to are updated, thus the originally assigned pointer doesn't point to the correct memory address.

**As you can see I am confused myself, which is why I want to know of *techniques or free programs* that assist me in determining WHEN & WHERE a pointer points to null or falls out of scope (dangling pointers? is that whats happening).**

Maybe I can just use a simple ASSERT call to determine when a pointer is null?

More info: Right now my problem is that I have a class that has member variables that are pointers. They are initialised in the constructor & by the end of the constructor those pointers points to correct objects. But in reactions to events, when I look at these pointers they are null/out of scope. I can determine this because 1. the program crashes & 2 the eclipse debugger shows them as red hollow circles (I think that means that point to NULL or are out of scope?).

Comment: I think you'll need to do better than this. If they become `NULL`, it's because something is setting them to `NULL`. I don't see how anyone who hasn't seen your code can say how. Oh, and by all means, put `ASSERT`s all over the place if you need to clarify what is happening. And, while you're at it, work at becoming better with the debugger as well.

Comment: You mention using Eclipse; are you on Windows and do you have/can use Visual Studio? Some versions of VS2010 and 2008 come with analysis built in that can help a good bit. You can also download the WDK and use PREfast from that.

Comment: Updating an object does *not* invalidate pointers pointing to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest two different tools:

- [Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net) is a static analyser that looks at your source code and tries to identify problems (with pointers, and with a lot of other things too).
- [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is a runtime tool that watches all the allocations and deallocations your program performs, and ensures that they are all correct.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill Thanks for the reply. I have had a look at Valgrind before, is it a GUI that you run while you program is running or is it a c library & I place valgrind c functions in my own code to inspect pointers?

Comment: Valgrind is neither - instead of running your program as `./myprogram` or whatever, you run `valgrind ./myprogram` and the output is written to the console. Its operation is almost entirely automatic, you don't have to modify your code at all.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: That is a gross misrepresentation. I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @Greg: I have looked harder.  CppCheck appears, based on its thin docs and close examination of the code, to basically match regular expressions over a version of the source code in which the tokens have been separted by spaces; some tokens sequences have been normalized. One can write C++ procedures using this matching to code more complex checks.  But it does not appear to have any notion of types, symbol tables, data or control flow.  I don't see how it can diagnose any real interesting errors.  One does not use a truly weak static analzyer on a truly tough language and expect good results.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: Cppcheck is a tradeoff, and is very much biased toward "pragmatic" rather than "perfection". No matter what its techniques, it manages to detect a lot of *real* problems in *real* code. It actually outperformed a commercial product that we had been using at work (codebase is ~2M lines of C++ written over the past 15 years or so).

Comment: @Greg:  I'm surprised.   If it works for you, more power to you. The foundations are extremely weak, certainly nowhere near what I expect from a static analysis tool let alone one for C++.  I don't suppose you'd tell us the name of the commercial product, so we can avoid it :-{

Comment: Sorry, I'd rather not, particularly in this context. The company was helpful but their product just didn't measure up.

Answer (score 1):

If the objects that are being pointed to are custom classes you can put a breakpoint in the destructor to see if/when it is being destroyed. If not, you can set a symbolic breakpoint for the destructor of that class.

Answer (score 1):

You need a data break point.  Visual Studio definitely has them.  GDB definitely has them - it may call them something else (watch points?).  I haven't used Eclipse, but it probably does too.

So you set a (regular) breakpoint in the constructor, so that the pointers are set up correctly.  Then pick one of the pointers, and put a data break point on it.  Then run.  The program will stop when something changes the value of the pointer.  That'll show you where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

make the data (pointer) private, and force a particular usage via assertions. for example:

```
class t_class {
public:
    /* ... */
    void invalidatePointer() {
    /* is a delete required??? */
        this->d_pointer = 0;
    }

    void setPointer(int* const p) {
        assert(p && "use invalidatePoiner");
        /* ...stuff... */
        this->d_pointer = p;
    }
private:
    int* d_pointer; /* you probably don't want a non-contained pointer here, either */
};
```